# How to call third party site's json api from shopify custom app

Tags: json, shopify

I created custom app in shopify admin. But I don't know how to call thirdparty site json api with that app. Can anyone help me about this.

Answer (score -1):

In your App, set up the App Proxy. That is an endpoint in your App, GET or POST that you can receive data at. Shopify will call that endpoint with security so you know inside your App the call is a good one. Since you are inside your secure App, this is the place where you can call your third-party API to get data. Once that call completes, you can return JSON to Shopify.

In Shopify theme, the call is /apps/my_end_point with data. Shopify mangles all that, and sends it to your Proxy. So your proxy get data from the front-end, and you can then safely call your APIs, and return JSON to Shopify.

Simple and elegant pattern of use you have to use. There really is no other way to do it securely.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for showing interest. There is no app proxy option in my custom app

Comment: So make a proper custom App using your Partner Dashboard.